# Crear archivos para importar-exportar: como guardar una jerarquía de entidades

Tags: c#, archivo

#### Situación

Hola a todos: estoy desarrollando una aplicación interna para la empresa en la que trabajo. Para que entendáis un poco más de problema, os dejo un poco la situación de como va. Se que a muchos no les gusta leer historias, si eres uno de esos puedes pasar al problema y la pregunta, pero quizás esto ayude a entenderlos mejor:

> La empresa es una consultoría de Ingeniería Industrial, y tenemos que
>   hacer estudios de tiempos, métodos, etc, etc.
>
> La cosa es, ahora estoy creando la versión interna que va a generar
>   los métodos, obtener las entradas, etc, etc con la que trabajaran los
>   empleados. Lleva ciertas utilidades de cronómetro, generación de
>   estudios, cálculos, etc etc.
>
> Estoy ejecutando una API REST que se ejecutará en la red local en la
>   oficina, que contiene la información del usuario, en qué proyectos
>   está trabajando el usuario, etc... Digamos que será como el gestor de
>   proyectos global. Pero luego viene la parte difícil que no sé cómo
>   hacer frente .
>
> Mi jefe me ha puesto como requisito que todo debe estar en archivos,
>   de los que el pueda hacer una copia de seguridad todos los días en sus
>   discos duros replicados.  En la actualidad, trabajan con archivos de
>   Excel y todo está organizado en un servidor / repositorio local con
>   una jerarquía de carpetas en la que residen todos estos archivos
>   excel.
>
> Ahora, están dando a los clientes un Pendrive con esa carpeta con todo
>   en Excels y demás archivos: a mi parecer, algo nada profesional de
>   cara al cliente. El objetivo con este nuevo software es dar a los
>   clientes una aplicación (que se desarrollará más tarde) donde se puede
>   abrir un archivo, llamado projectname.project, o algo así. Cuando
>   importen dicho archivo, que tiene todo el proyecto en él, podrán ver
>   toda la información, estudios, estadísticas, etc, etc... que
>   pertenecen a ese proyecto, con solo abrir un archivo. Hay que tener en
>   cuenta que una empresa puede tener múltiples proyectos, así que
>   tendrán muchos archivos de ese tipo.

---

#### Problema

La jerarquía de entidades de todo el sistema es la siguiente:

> - Empresa
>
>   - Proyecto 1
>   - Proyecto 2
>   - Proyecto 3
>
>     - Informe tipo 1
>     - Informe tipo 2
>     - Estudio 1
>     - Estudio 2
>     - Estudio 3
>
>       - Tarea 1
>       - Tarea 2
>       - Tarea 3

Ahora, para la aplicación local, la utilizada por nuestros empleados, todo se almacena por separado y se carga como lo necesitan desde nuestro servidor interno. Cada entidad de esa lista se guarda como un archivo binario, pero no contiene la entidad que lleva por debajo, solo ella misma.

El **problema** viene cuando tengo que **exportar esto en algún formato que el cliente pueda importar y ver todo al completo**: no puede recibir 100 archivos, debe recibir uno que cargue todo el proyecto en la aplicación cliente.

---

#### Pregunta

Dicho esto, que la información se almacena en ficheros localmente, referenciada por una base de datos MySQL que hace las relaciones entre ellos, los usuarios, etc.

**¿Cómo puedo generar un archivo, con cualquier extensión, que se puede dar a un cliente por correo electrónico, por ejemplo, de modo que solo tenga que abrir la nueva aplicación y simplemente abrir el archivo y tener acceso a toda la jerarquía que escribo por encima de estas líneas? El proceso es como fusionar todos los archivos en uno solo, pero ¿cómo puedo hacer eso?**

Mi primer enfoque es crear otra aplicación (o una sección en la aplicación) que generará una clase de objeto enorme llamada Proyecto, iterando cargando todos los archivos en clases y metiéndolas en la clase Proyecto en listas, de modo que se genere una especie de arbol y, a continuación, guardar ese objeto de proyecto en un archivo, pero no estoy seguro si va a funcionar, ya que estamos hablando de unas 100 tareas para cada estudio, 50 estudios para cada proyecto... y no estoy seguro si la aplicación podrá soportar la carga de leer tooodos los archivos uno a uno, generar ese árbol y después volver a binarizarlo.

---

#### Código actual

No hay mucho que mostrar con respecto al problema, lo que hago ahora con cada parte del proyecto es guardar esa clase de objeto en un archivo y hacer referencia a ella en la base de datos para luego ir cargándolas según se soliciten.

Genero los archivos y los leo con estos métodos de mi clase `Herramientas`:

```
public static void WriteToBinaryFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, append ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create))
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToWrite);
    }
}

public static T ReadFromBinaryFile<T>(string filePath)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: no termino de entender tu problema (aunque hay una larga explicacion). es como generar los archivos? o si necesitas otro programa para generarlos? o cual es el problema concreto? porque esto se puede hacer de miles de formas.

Comment: Podrías generar un xml con los datos

Comment: @gbianchi Intentaba hacerlo bien con una buena explicación, pero veo que al final va a causar más problemas tanta explicación en lugar de poner 3 líneas. Lo que quiero saber es como puedo hacer para exportar todas las entidades colgando de una. Si hay algún procedimiento especifico que se suela seguir en estos casos o directamente es realizar un arbol que contenga todos los datos y exportarlos, ya sea a XML, binario, etc. Pero para eso necesito leer todos los datos primero y meterlos en una sola estructura, lo que creo que podría ser muy pesado para la aplicación y podría quedarse colgada.

Comment: @miguel no me interesa un XML, necesito que este binarizado para que no puedan crearse su propio programa y cargar los XML como ellos quieran...

Comment: Si es requisito que no "puedan" modificarlo, firma el xml y así te aseguras la integridad de los datos

Comment: La diferencia entre un XML y un binario no importa. Los datos se guardan de la misma forma con los métodos que he incluido en la pregunta y además, he leído en SOen que el binario es mucho más rápido a la hora de leer/escribir que el XML. Así que eso no es problema.

Comment: No. No se donde viste, pero el tiempo de lectura de un archivo depende del disco rigido, no del formato de los datos. Puede que sea mas rapido porque en binario los datos estarian "comprimidos", pero el texto es texto en binario o plano. Tu problema es hacer un archivo de export? que impideria que mandes el backup de tu base de datos (como idea loca)

Comment: Como digo en la pregunta, no quiero enviar una base de datos que tengan que importar a un servidor con un mysql y un php activos para que tengan una API REST funcionando etc etc... quiero una aplicación completamente standalone, que solo tengan que instalar en su ordenador y poder abrir todos nuestros proyectos con solo abrir un archivo que termine en .proyectoMiEmpresa. Esta es la complicación. Además, si lees la pregunta, no todo esta almacenado en la DB, sino que esta todo en archivos dentro del servidor/repositorio local.

Comment: @gbianchi En cuanto al tema de la velocidad: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904494/why-is-binary-serialization-faster-than-xml-serialization

Comment: @DaniAguado ok dani. Ahi estas serializando objetos. Aca hablabas de datos en la base de datos. Para el caso, entonces un TXT con formato plano propio seria todavia mas rapido. Y respecto de tu link, concuerdo mas con la tercer respuesta, de que depende el caso. Y de que tamaño es lo que vas a mandar?

Comment: @gbianchi Te invito a que por favor leas la sección *Pregunta* de mi Pregunta (Valga la redundancia). Ahí indico que tengo ficheros almacenados, referenciados por base de datos (para decir donde estan, que nombre tienen y a que proyecto pertenecen, nada más), y además explico la dimensión de archivos de la que estamos hablando.

Comment: ven al [chat] si puedes. Lei todo eso, y siguen siendo pocos datos (por lo menos para lo que manejo yo usualmente)